# Checking and setting a C++ project build flags in Visual Studio 13

Tags: c++, build, flags

this may be a beginner question but I really don't know the answer.
I want to check my project build flags if they are set as said in the table that is attached but I don't know where to find them and how to set them.
This may be for a very specific project so if more information is needed for answering my question I will provide.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXHvO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Project build flags are found in the property manager. In at least some versions of Visual Studio you can find that under "view" / "property manager".